# Facebook sdk using php: how to get theuserid of the connected user

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, facebook-php-sdk, userid

how can i get the current logged in userid ?

im pretty sure my appId is correct

```
  $facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '...',
  'secret' => '...',
));
```

im using this method but i returns 0;

```
$facebook->getUser();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get facebook user id with this code

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
   'appId'  => 'your_app_id',
   'secret' => 'your_app_secret',
));     
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

You have condition to should have done before, the first condition is you put that code in the page that redirected after the user login via fb provide by this code

```
$params = array(
    'display'=>'popup',
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://example.com'
);
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

OR the second condition is you already have the user 'Access Token', so the code will be like this

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
   'appId'  => 'your_app_id',
   'secret' => 'your_app_secret',
));     
$facebook->setAccessToken('user_access_token');
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

If you don't clear about the Facebook Login flow using PHP SDK, you can visit this [page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$myData=$facebook->api('/me');
```

### $myid=myData['id'];

### $myName=myData['name'];

### $myUsername=myData['username'];

```
[id] => your id
[name] => your full name
[first_name] => your firs name
[last_name] => lastname
[link] => profil link
[username] => username
[gender] => your gender (male,female)
[email] => your mail (if have email permission)
[timezone] => 2
[locale] => your locale
[verified] => 1
```

Comment: will this work to other user, not only me? the idea is i want to get the facebook userid visiting my website.

Comment: This Code get all persons informations Connect to your site..

me= Connected user
if your connected  this code get your informations
if some one connected this code get they informations.

if you want record this informations use php or asp save all to  database

for example.
Mahmut connected yor site and accept your app
This code get Mahmut's İnformations..

$myData=$facebook->api('/me');
$myname=myData['name'];   -----> $myname = Mahmut Duman  not your name just connected user informations

Take care vavien .. (sory my english is bad)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this guide: [Login for Server-side Apps](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/). Basically, you have to generate a login URL, receive a code generated by Facebook, and with this code, request for an access token.